# What is this plant? - indoor not growing well

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, indoors

[image]

I have had this plant for a while but have no idea what it is.

Comment: Plants need light, and fresh soil once every 5 years. Other than that, it's a creeping tropical plant.